# POI - Can't open xslx files in osgi

Tags: java, excel, osgi, apache-camel, apache-poi

Getting the next exception when trying to read xlsx files in osgi (jboss-fuse). Xls is working fine.

Using the next jar files inside the bundle :

```
<br>
lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, \<br>
lib/poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203.jar, \<br>
lib/poi-3.9-20121203.jar, \<br>
lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, \<br>
lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar, \<br>
lib/poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar, \<br>
lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar, \<br>
lib/poi-excelant-3.9-20121203.jar, \<br>
lib/xmlbeans-xpath-2.3.0.jar   <br>
```

> 117-org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.12.0.redhat-610379 | ** **org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: 
>   Can't read content types part !**
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.(ContentTypeManager.java:107)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.(ZipContentTypeManager.java:56)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:188)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:665)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:274)
>       at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:79)

Comment: Why are you mixing POI jars from different versions? You seem to have a nasty mix of 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11 POI jars, which is completely unsupported and likely to break in odd ways!

Comment: Thanks. Actually that lib mess was after numerous attempts to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So adding the next file "org.xml.sax.driver" under META-INF/services in the bundle helps.
Contents of the file:
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo

Updating poi to the latest version 3.11 fixed the issue without that file:

> lib/poi-scratchpad-3.11.jar, \
>      lib/poi-3.11.jar, \
>      lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11.jar, \
>      lib/poi-ooxml-3.11.jar, \
>      lib/poi-excelant-3.11.jar, \
>      lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar, \
>      lib/xmlbeans-xpath-2.6.0.jar